# JaveScript Select the dropdown list by the text of options

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to select the dropdown list by using the display-text of the options in the console(JavaScript)?

In my workplace, I need to fill a web form every day. But the options are too much to load, so I hope to use the Chrome console to select the option instead of using the mouse to click.

For now, I can use Value to select the option, but when I try to use the text, it fails.
The HTML sample and the JavaScript I used are as below. Could someone help?

```
Success - document.querySelector("#sel").value = 123
Fails - document.querySelector("#sel").text = "Product A"

<select>
<option value="123"> Product A </option>
<option value="243"> Product B </option>
<option value="212"> Product C </option>
<option value="466"> Product D </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to set the `text` property of a select element?

Comment: There's no `sel` id anywhere in your sample HTML

Answer (score 0):

`Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('option')).find(el => el.textContent === 'Product A');`

Answer (score 0):

Truly sorry for the confusing example.
After trying lots of solutions, the final coding as below:

```
var txt = prompt();
for (i = 0; i < document.querySelector("#sel").options.length; i++) {
    if(document.querySelector("#sel").options[i].text == txt){
        document.querySelector("#sel").options[i].selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

With these codes, the User can select the specific options by entering the name of the product instead of clicking the dropdown list with the mouse and crash the browser.